# Client rsyslog and server in the same machine Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

I am wondering if I can make Rsyslog to receive logs from my own IP, I just want to test that the configurations work, right now I dont have access to another PC or Server, just my PC, in few words I want to make a client and server in one computer to test it, the problem is, I dont get any log, I have checked /var/syslog and nothing
, I am running Ubuntu 14.04

In my /etc/rsyslog.conf:

```
    # provides UDP syslog reception
    $ModLoad imudp
    $UDPServerRun 514

    # provides TCP syslog reception
    $ModLoad imtcp
    $InputTCPServerRun 514
```

in my /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf:

```
    local1.* @127.0.0.1:514
```

Thanks in advance! And sorry I am a litle noob with logs :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out, I just had to add this in /etc/rsyslog.conf:

```
    $template RemoteHost,"/var/log/%HOSTNAME%/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%$DAY%/syslog.log"
    *.* ?RemoteHost
    *.* @@127.0.0.1:514
    & ~
```